# Add value to the last empty cell in a defined dynamic column

Tags: database, excel, vba

My model takes two numbers from one sheet, adds the average to another sheet in the last cell of a defined column. The problem that I have is that when I insert a new column, the references get missed up and I'm trying to have a macro that would 1. take the average 2. look for a specific column on the second sheet 3. paste the averaged value to the last cell.

Please help me with this I have been trying to get my head around it for a long time.

my problem is that I have to insert new columns and I need to keep the references dynamic when adding a value to the last empty cell in a column. For example: if i have salary as col A, and expenses as Col B - in this model that I have now I put in .Cells(emptyRow, 1) and .Cells(emptyRow, 2) now if I insert a column between A and B the references 1 and 2 will not work. Is there anyway that I can work around this where if i add a new column it wont mess up the references in the macro? 
Thank you.

This is the code that I have right now but it does not really work - when I insert a new column the column defined name does not shift right.

```
Sub demo()

    Dim expCol As Long, FirstEmptyRow As Long

    Range("B:B").Cells.Name = "expenses"

    expCol = Range("expenses").Column

    FirstEmptyRow = Cells(Rows.Count, expCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Cells(FirstEmptyRow, expCol).Value = 123

End Sub
```

P.S. 123 here is just an example for testing purposes. The value that would replace it in my model is the average I talk about in the question.

Comment: I am a strong advocate of moving Totals at the TOP of lists. It simplifies your life and allows users to have the totals always  visible by freezing the first row(s).

Comment: Have you looked into Excel Tables / ListObjects? Then you can name columns and all the totaling / name changing happens for you automatically....

Comment: @iDevelop I have a database of prices of different commodities. The list goes down to input a new price every day for each item. Sometimes I need to insert a new column for a commodity in between other ones and this is my problem: I cannot find a way to automate the references so I dont have to open the macro and edit the references for each column. Any suggestions?

Comment: @johnbustos can you please give me an example of what to look for?

Comment: Just do a google search for "Excel Tables VBA" / "Excel VBA ListObject" or something similar... I just did it and found this link that teaches you a lot, but isn't pretty to read through: http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/Excel2007Tables.asp  OR  http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/Excel2007TablesVBA.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your columns have headers (I guess they do), and your data has no gaps just use 
`Range("1:1").Find(columnName).End(xlDown).Offset(1,0) = 123`

If a column can have just a header but no values, you need to add additional check if second row isn't empty.

Comment: It worked :) I'm new to stackoverflow but I'll upvote your answer when I get enough reputation points - Thank you

Comment: what additional check I need to add? What I would like to do is when I insert a new column I want start inputing data on the same last empty row of other columns though the new column (has a header) but does not have values yet.

Comment: Ohh, so I misunderstood a little. Does each row contain only one value in one of all columns? Or you need to refer next/previous column to find correct place?

Comment: Let's say I have three columns of Item 1, Item 2 and Item 3. These three columns already have values down to a specific row. Now I need to insert a new column between Item 2 and Item 3. I would like to be able to add this column and input values across all items on the same last empty row and so on. The new column's values will start on that last empty row (to be filled) across all columns.

Comment: Does first column contain dates? Or is always filled some other way? It would be the easiest to be able to reference one column that is sure to have data in place.

Comment: It has dates (never moves as a column) so each day it would input today's date to the last empty row and I have a macro that inputs new values across all items for that day.

Comment: any idea about what additional checks I need to add because I will have columns with just headers and no data (when created new to start accepting values)? Thanks a lot

Comment: Then try 
`Cells(Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1.0).Row, Range("1:1").Find(columnName).Column) = 123`

Answer (score 0):

If you create a named range this way (rather than the `Range.Cells.Name` way you were using), then when inserting columns the reference will be dynamic.  Now if you insert columns between A and B later in the code, you can still use `expCol` and `FirstEmptyRow` to reference the first empty cell in the expenses column, where ever it may have moved to on the sheet, as long as you update them after each column insertion.

```
Sub Demo()
Dim expensesrng As Range
Dim Expenses As Range
Dim expCol As Long
Dim Exprng  As Range
Dim FirstEmptyRow  As Long

'set the original range to use for the expense column
Set expensesrng = Range(Range("B1"), Range("B1").End(xlDown))
'add the named range
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Expenses", RefersTo:=expensesrng
' create a variable to refer to the Expenses Range
Set Exprng = ActiveWorkbook.Names("Expenses").RefersToRange

expCol = ActiveWorkbook.Names("Expenses").RefersToRange.Column
FirstEmptyRow = Exprng.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Row

Cells(FirstEmptyRow, expCol).Value = 123

'after inserting columns then you will have to get/update the column number
'of the expense named range and the first empty row before adding your new expense   
'data to it

Range("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlShiftToRight
expCol = ActiveWorkbook.Names("Expenses").RefersToRange.Column
FirstEmptyRow = expensesrng.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Row

Cells(FirstEmptyRow, expCol).Value = 123

End Sub
```

Comment: this works great but I'm looking for a way to help me avoid going into the macro every time i insert new column to update a reference manually.

Comment: Aren't you using a macro to add the "123" data each time?  You could alter that macro to use references to the named ranges to locate the column and the first empty cell. Any columns that have just a header and are empty, you could use range.offset from a known range location to get to a cell you want.  Maybe posting an image of how the data is laid out would help.

Comment: 123 here is just an example for testing purposes. The value that would replace it in my model is the average of two values that the macro calculates. My data looks like this: Let's say I have three columns of Item 1, Item 2 and Item 3. These three columns already have values down to a specific row. Now I need to insert a new column between Item 2 and Item 3. I would like to be able to add this column and input values across all items on the same last empty row and so on. The new column's values will start on that last empty row (to be filled) across all columns. The first column is date.